# Err 1064 References Line 8 mysql

Tags: mysql, reference

Hey guys i'm kind of new to the whole world of mysql, the current problem i have is that i can't quite work out why this is not working is it possibly to do with the 2 primary keys? Or is it the references? Thanks in advance

```
CREATE TABLE IsSeenBy 
(  PatientCode int (11) NOT NULL,
   DoctorCode int (11) NOT NULL,
   Date VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL, 
   Time VARCHAR (5) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (PatientCode), 
   PRIMARY KEY (DoctorCode),
   PatientCode REFERENCES (Patient),
   DoctorCode REFERENCES (Doctor)
;
```

Comment: looks like you are missing a close bracket ')'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date is a reserved word so if you want to name a column that you will need to quote it. Also I'd highly recommend using an actual Date type for that column, not VARCHAR. (unless it needs to be something like a star date.) And yes, you cannot have two primary keys. You need either one or a compound one. Your foreign key definitions do not look correct either

```
CREATE TABLE IsSeenBy 
(PatientCode int (11) NOT NULL,
DoctorCode int (11) NOT NULL,
`Date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (PatientCode, DoctorCode),
FOREIGN KEY (PatientCode)
REFERENCES Patient(PatientCode)
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
FOREIGN KEY (DoctorCode)
REFERENCES Doctor(`DoctorCode`)
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT

);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help it's greatly appreciated. The date and time part looks a lot better than what I was aiming for, didn't know you could have a dropdown box :D

Comment: If you continue to have problems make sure they are all InnoDB tables ( you may need to add `Engine = InnoDB` to the end of the create statements, after the closing karen but before the semicolon) and that the columns in the referenced tables are indexed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have 2 PK in the table. If you want composite PK use

```
PRIMARY KEY (PatientCode, DoctorCode),
```

instead.

You must explore Foreign key reference documentation too.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i'm still getting the same error due to the references part i think.